# Spring WebFlux consumer to sink

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Here is a simple spring boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ReactiveApplication {

    static Flux<String> fluxString;
    static volatile Queue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueueProxy();

    private static class ConcurrentLinkedQueueProxy extends ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public boolean add(String e) {
            synchronized (this) {
                notify();
            }
            return super.add(e);
        }

        @Override
        public String poll() {
            synchronized (this) {
                if(isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
                }
            }
            return super.peek() == null ? "" : super.poll();
        }
    }

    static Consumer<String> consumer = str -> queue.add(str);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveApplication.class, args);
    }

    static {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            queue.add("testData " + i + " ");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> home() {

        Scheduler sch = Schedulers.newParallel("parallel-sch", 1);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(queue);
        queue.removeAll(queue);

        fluxString = Flux.<String>create(sink -> {
            sink.onRequest(n -> {
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    sink.next(queue.poll());
                }
            }).onCancel(() -> sch.dispose());
        }).log().subscribeOn(sch).mergeWith(Flux.<String>fromIterable(list));

        return fluxString;

    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String add( @RequestParam String s) {
        consumer.accept(s);
        return s;
    }

}
```

So basically this application creates a String stream. Visiting `/` will grab all the string present queue and then merge anything that is added from `/add` resource(ignore the "Safe Methods Must be Idempotent" thing).

What I feel is strange is that when I move `public static void main(...)` to line 1, the application starts to misbehave and adding new values to `/add` doesn't have any effect. I think there must be something interesting going on that is making application misbehave. Any explaination?

Comment: i have never seen anyone trying to write an application in one single class. Why not just follow the guidelines and recommendations and place your controller in a separate class.  Because its obvious you will get strange behavior if you are not following the general guidelines.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I was just playing around with this stuff. Turns out the "static variables are initialized by sequence" is the answer, it has nothing to do with mixing of stuff. Anyways, I have a new question if you could help me with. If two clients are subscribed to `/`, the string added using `/add` is distributed in round-robin manner. Now if a client disconnects, it still takes 2 calls to `/add` to appear on the subscriber `/` endpoint. This problem increases linearly. Looks like `sch.dispose()` is doing nothing. Any thoughts? I have tested it by seperating the concerns too.

Comment: `onCancel` only gets triggered on a cancel signal from the calling client. A disconnect is not a cancel signal, https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_cleaning_up_after_push_or_create

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I had the same doubt after reading the reference but a quick sysout in `onCancel` cleared it. The cancel event is infact generated. Even after verifying that, I tried a `.subscribeOn(sch).doFinally(signal -> {...)` without any benefit. What I figured out after looking at the logs is that the thread created by `Schedulers.newParallel` is not being terminated even after `scr.dispose()`. But I have no idea on how to get the handle to that thread or manipulate it. I have read the docs, source and reference but I got lost.

Comment: is there any reason as to why you need it on its separate scheduler? A common reason to place execution on a schedular is for paralellism during blocking calls. There are a certin amount of threads in the forkjoinpool and we dont want to occupy these for blocking calls. But as soon as you place something on a scheduler i belive its ”on its own”

Comment: But im no expert here, just want to say that

Comment: @ThomasAndolf The requirement for scheduler is because I made `ConcurrentLinkedQueueProxy#poll` block until next element is added by `ConcurrentLinkedQueueProxy#add`. And this is the reason of what I think is preventing the thread from disposing it. `BlockingQueue` has the same characteristics as `ConcurrentLinkedQueueProxy`. If I remove the scheduler, the main thread that is working on the hot stream gets blocked and there is no `onNext` event generated.

Comment: Any longgoing threads should according to the documentarion be placed on a elasticBounded scheduler

Comment: @ThomasAndolf It has nothing to do with it. But thankyou for your help :) Really appreciate it :) I posted the code I ended up with.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf The problem was with `.create(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this which works great:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ReactiveApplication {

    private static BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
    private static Consumer<String> consumer = str -> {
        try { queue.put(str); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    };
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) queue.add("testData " + i + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> home() {

        final Scheduler sch = Schedulers.newSingle("async-flux");

        return Flux.<String>generate(sink -> {
            try { sink.next(queue.take()); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }).log().subscribeOn(sch);

    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String add(@RequestParam String s) {
        consumer.accept(s);
        return s;
    }

}
```